# Application Insights same queries but different answers

Tags: azure

I create 2 logical equal queries in Application Insights but receive different answers:

requests | summarize count(itemCount)
and
requests | summarize sum(itemCount)

These queries have different values in my Application, what can be reason?

Comment: can you please try to add a timestamp as a condition? like: requests 
| where timestamp >= todatetime('2019-07-08T05:17:24.9197104Z') and timestamp <= todatetime('2019-07-08T05:30:32.9303994Z')
| summarize count(itemCount)

Comment: i found answer, itemcount could be grater then 1 it is depend on sampling your data

Comment: You can put your findings as an answer. It would be helpful for others.

Comment: i put it in previos time but moderator delete it because of external link to microsoft portal=)

Answer (score 0):

I think that itemCount ==1 but it can be grater then 1 it is depends on sampling your data microsoft docs "Sampling in Application Insights". That's why my expressions give me a differents answers. 'Count' show us how many 'itemCount', but sum equal sum itemcounts values.